# Is there a way to define the Display Name in the Sign up and Sign in user flow in Azure AD B2C?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

Is there a way to define the Display Name(label) and User Input type for the ***Sign up and Sign in***  user flow in Azure AD B2C out of the box?

We are having several custom attributes for which we need to set a user-friendly display name. However, the recommended  ***Sign up and sign In*** policy doesn’t seem to support this out of the box. The Sign Up only policy has UI to define the Display Name (in Label). We can use two separate policies ***Sign Up***  and ***Sign In***, but the later doesn’t support to select templates.

Comment: Did you try with Localization in Signup and signin policy?

Comment: As above, try https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-flow-language-customization

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Yes, we tried updating the policy (json manual edit) and it worked, but wondering if there is a direct UI like the other Sign Up only policy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there is no direct UI for **Sign up and sign In** policy and **Sign In** policy. You need to customize the label manually by editing the file.

Reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-flow-language-customization

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/customize-ui-overview